# Reference request for Thom's Transversality Theorem.

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, transversality, h-principle

I am trying to read the book *Introduction to the h-principle* by Eliashberg and Mishachev. I am unable to understand the proof of Thom's Transversality theorem in the book. So if anyone can give any alternate reference or explain the main idea in the proof it would be great.

The statement I am looking for is

"Let $X \to V$ be a fibrebundle and W a submanifold of jet space $X^r$. Then for a generic section $f:V \to X$ its jet extension is transversal to W."

Comment: That book is written by two people not one. It is immensely rude and disrespectful to only include the name of the author whose name happens to come first alphabetically.

Comment: @PVAL I am sorry and thank you for correcting it.

Comment: I believe this should be in Hirsch' differential topology

Comment: Another good reference for jet transversality is Guillemin and Golubitsky, *Stable Mappings and their Singularities*.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks a lot I really like your reference but it seems to me that the method of proof is very different from the one given in Introduction to h-principle. Do you know some reference which elaborates on the proof in Introduction to h-principle?